# how to write everything from jtextarea to file in real time. it is something like log all info displayed into log filefile

Tags: java, swing, logging, file-io, jtextarea

I have no code yet I just looking for possible solutions. I will have jtextarea to output information with textarea.append and at the same time I will need to write the same string to the some kind of log file.is it possible to use logging api? I have an option to create method with textarea.append and write to file the same string but it seems to me too messy.
Thank you

Comment: You could use a logging API. You would need some kind of method you could call that would append the text to the text area and write the same String to the logger

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this should not be a problem.
You can create a custom appender that writes to the TextArea.
To only challenge here is how to get a reference to the TextArea.
Of course you could have some static method that returns this reference but a cleaner solution might be to use [Markers](http://www.baptiste-wicht.com/2010/02/logging-with-slf4j/2/).

Comment: That's an interesting idea. Just for my clarification, would this mean you could set it up so that your (custom) class would become an appender, allowing you to write to the text area when ever something is written to the logger?

Comment: Indeed, apart from getting the reference from the TextArea this is quite straightforward.

Comment: Thank you. But what would be more efficient? And is it hard to lmplement logging? I have no idea about logging thats why I thought this should be easy way of doing it

Comment: Not enough information to determine that. If this is the only use case then using a custom logger is a bit of an overkill and simply appending to the TextArea and then to some writer makes more sense.